# ¿Como mostrar distintos mensajes al ingresar datos duplicados a la base de datos?Php/MySql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, backend

## ¡Hola!

Estoy intentando que,cuando el usuario ingrese el nombre de una region,si la misma es repetida se muestre en pantalla "Ocurrio un error",pero no puedo.

**Region.php:**

```
class Region
{
    private $regID;
    private $regNombre;

    private function cargarDatosDesdeForm()
    {

          if(isset($_POST["regID"]))
          {
              $this->setRegID($_POST["regID"]);
          }

          if(isset($_POST["regNombre"]))
          {
              $this->setRegNombre($_POST["regNombre"]);
          }
     }

       public function agregarRegion()
       {
            $this->cargarDatosDesdeForm();

            $link = Conexion::conectar();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO regiones(regNombre) VALUES (:regNombre)";

            $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);

            $regNombre = $this->getRegNombre();

            $stmt->bindParam(":regNombre",$regNombre,PDO::PARAM_STR);

            if($stmt->execute())
            { 
                return true;
            }
          return false;
       }
}
```

**agregarRegion.php:**

```
<?php 
   require "clases/Conexion.php";
   require "clases/Region.php";

     $objRegion = new Region();

      $objRegion->agregarRegion();

         if($objRegion){
 ?>
         <p>Region agregada</p>
    <?php }else{ ?>

      <p>Lo siento,ocurrio un error.</p>

          <?php /*if('codigo de error==666'){ //Con el codigo de error mostrar esto:
                     <p>Ya hay una region con ese nombre.</p>
                   }*/?>


  <?php } ?>
```

Pero lo que veo en pantalla es lo siguiente:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'America' for key 'regNombre' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\clases\Region.php on line 60
>
> Region agregada

- ¿Como puedo hacer para que no se vea el mensaje de error?
- ¿Como puedo hacer para que si hay un error no aparezca en pantalla Region Agregada,sino "Ocurrio un error"?
- ¿Y para que con el codigo de error de mysql saber si el error es que el nombre es repetido?

PD: El campo regNombre es unico.

Answer (score 1):

Hola colega espero te sirva u oriente

```
  try {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO regiones(regNombre) VALUES (:regNombre)";

         $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);

         $regNombre = $this->getRegNombre();

         $stmt->bindParam(":regNombre",$regNombre,PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->execute();
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
      if ($e->getCode() === 23000) { // numero del error para Duplicate entry '%s' for key %d 
          //hacer algo
     }
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getcode.php

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_key

Comment: Lo que hice fue lo siguiente: 
`try {
                               $stmt->execute();
                      } catch (\PDOException $e) {      
                              echo "Ocurrio el siguiente codigo de error:" . $e->getCode();     
                           return false;
                      }`
Pero es como si el metodo no entrara en el catch,probe poniendo ruido imprimendo con un echo pero aun asi no pasa nada...

Comment: Despues de mucho renegar lo logre,gracias por la orientación!
Solo que no use `catch(\PDOException $e)` sino que use `catch(Exception $e)`
¿Hay alguna diferencia?

Comment: Feliz de ayudar!, la verdad no sabria contestarte a ciencia cierta pero si te funciona como deseas no creo que haya problema. Te dejo un enlace que igual te puede ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152147/php-why-are-there-exceptions-of-different-classes-ex-pdoexception-vs-exceptio